# Offline page has bad background image

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The offline page for this site points to an image on "cd**m**.sstactic.net" for its background, but it should be "cdn.sstatic.net":

```
background: transparent url('http://cdm.sstatic.net/scifi/img/bg-site.jpg') repeat left top;
```

The background colour should likely also be specified as something dark, in case the image doesn't load for some reason, because of the light colour used for the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have put in a fix for this. The url was indeed misspelled! Thanks.